# Delete custom object from vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code to store objects of type LVA in a vector.
I've implemented a method for adding a LVA Object to the vector. 
First question: Is it okay if i use a reference to the LVA object in this method?

Now i want to implement a method for the deletion of a LVA object. I want to have the following method signature: `void RemoveLVA(LVA& lva)`. How can I implement this method? i.e. How can i find the right object in the vector to delete it?

Manager.h

```
class Manager {
public:
    Manager();
    Manager(const Manager& orig);
    virtual ~Manager();
    vector<LVA> GetLvas() const;
    void AddLva(LVA& lva);
private:
    vector<LVA> lvas;

};
```

Manager.cpp:

```
#include "Manager.h"

Manager::Manager() {
}

Manager::Manager(const Manager& orig) {
}

Manager::~Manager() {
}

vector<LVA> Manager::GetLvas() const {
    return lvas;
}

void Manager::AddLva(LVA& lva) {
    lvas.push_back(lva);
}
```

Comment: In both of your specific cases, a parameter of `const LVA& lva` makes the signature of your code more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay if i use a reference to the LVA object in AddLva(LVA& lva)?

Yes, `std::vector` will have a *copy* of your original object after `push_back()` is complete.

> How can I implement RemoveLVA(LVA& lva)?

You will need to find the object in your vector. (You may use `std::find()` if `operator==()` is defined for `LVA`.) Then invoke the `erase()` function for your vector.

Comment: thank you, so the right way for this approach is to override the == operator in the LVA class? then i can do something like `if lvaToDelete == lvaInVector then delete it`

Comment: @user1291235 With iterators, you would just use `lvas.erase(std::find(lvas.begin(), lvas.end(), lva))`

Comment: @user1291235 Maybe.  If `==` makes sense and has a generally recognized semantic for your object, then use it.  If the definition of equivalence is specific to this container, then it would be preferable to define a functional object to handle the case.

Comment: @chrisaycock Or `lvas.erase( std::remove( lvas.begin(), lvas.end(), lva ), lvas.end() )`, if there may be more than one element.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, that's a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay if i use a reference to the LVA object in this method?

No problem. You are actually doing a copy by a `push_back` operation.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about `LVA`, it's hard to be precise, but
you probably want a const reference for `AddLva`, since you're
not modifying it in the function (and you may want to pass
a temporary).

For removal: you'll have to define some sort of
equivalence function over `LVA` is you want to remove a matching
element.  This can be `LVA::operator==`, or some other object or
function: in the first case, you use `std::find` to find the
position, and in the second, `std::find_if`.  If the vector can contain
more than one matching element, you might want to look into `std::remove` or `std::remove_if`.

Answer (score 0):

Your insertion method is right, but don't forget that only a copy from your LVA object is inserted in the vector. it means than in the `RemoveLVA` method, you will need to use somthing like an `operator==` overload to `std::find` the vector's object which matches your parameter, and then deleting it.

You may prefer to insert pointers or `std::shared_ptr` of LVA in your vector. No object copy will then occur, and the search of an object will fall back to a comparison of pointer, given you keep the pointer somewhere else in your program (2 objects with same contents and different stack or heap locations would then compare to false).

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Presumably for polymorphism, though no mention is made of this anywahere.  I'm giving rems4e the benefit of the doubt here, though.

Comment: No copy if he only want to reference his objects for instance. And right John, I even forgot about that :)

Comment: @rems4e If you want to avoid copying, you can without resorting to pointers. Simply add temporaries to the vector – `push_back` has an appropriate overload for that. Lacking that, use `std::move`.

Comment: @JohnDibling Or identity.  But those are normally special cases; the "default" in C++ should always be value semantics.

Comment: Like I said, he may only want to reference his objects which belong somewhere else in the code, and then moving them wouldn't be acceptable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The guy isn't even sure whether he can use references, and you want to introduce him to the subtilities of move semantics?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Agreed.  I can't say I really agree with this answer posted by rems4e.

Comment: @James No. I want to make him less afraid of value semantics. Turning this around: the guy isn’t even sure whether he can use references, and you want to introduce him to the subtleties of pointer semantics? ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph What pointer semantics?  There are no pointers anywhere.

Comment: @James I quote from your own comment above: “Why on earth would he prefer pointers?”

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `AddLva` can take a reference, although it would typically take a `const` reference:

```
void Manager::AddLva(const LVA& lva) {
    lvas.push_back(lva);
}
```

Note however that if you are expecting that the reference is added to the `vector`, this isn't doing that.  A copy of the object `lva` refers to is made, and that copy is added to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's Ok to pass the LVA object as ref in your add and remove method. You could also declare those parameters as 'const' because I suppose add and remove will not affect the object .

for the remove method

```
void RemoveLVA(const LVA& lva)
{
    std::vector<LVA>::iterator position =
    std::find(lvas.begin(), lvas.end(), lva);
    if (position != lvas.end())
    {
        lvas.erase(position);
    }
}
```

but LVA class must have an == operator.

good luck.